# Possible to use javascript GAPI without including the '?onload=' at the end of the source?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api

I'm developing an application in Angular, and the google interactions will be within a service that I can use throughout the app. For this reason, I cannot do the usual method of adding in a function name at the end because I need for the service to be set up for the rest of the application to work correctly.

Currently what I have is the following

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var clientId = 'something something dark side.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  //The client ID, NECESSARY
  var apiKey = 'My API KEY';
  //Api Key
  var scopes = ['profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
  //The scopes, of which you will need
  (function(gapi) {
    console.log(gapi);
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      'client_id': clientId,
      'scope': scopes.join(' '),
      'immediate': true
    }, handleAuthResult);
  })(gapi);
  // rest of code below here.
</script>
```

My problem is that I get the following output in the console, which shows that `gapi.auth.authorize` is definitely there, so the error I am getting doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

[image: Errors]

I appreciate any help on this as I've been banging my head on it for about a week now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this is documented for someone in the future, it ***is*** possible, but it's not a very good work around that I got going. For anyone who will see this, please keep in mind that the code is a working progress and I literally *just* got the code working how it should be.

What I've come to find out is that the google api (gapi) isn't totally loaded when you include the script (which is why I would randomly receive the "gapi.auth.authorize is not a function" error). Most of the confusion originally arose from the fact that the google developer console is a tricky little thing -- it will take an object being put out at a given time and call `.toString()` on it, given you the string output of the object *the moment you called console.log()*. However, if you are like me, you will tend to click on it and do exactly what I was doing **"but, it's there!"**

What the gapi does then is load some more resources, but because those tend to be added in after our code will be the problem of "it works 100% as expected 50% of the time." However, google is nice enough to add an attribute `gapi_processed` and set it to true when the data has been loaded.

**to reiterate: this code is code I literally just got working and therefore is a twitch messy. Do not comment about *proper* ways to do something you see, trust me, I'm working on it. I just want this documented before I forget**

```
var config = {
    templatePath: 'templates/'
};

angular.module('rpiCalendar', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
    .service('gapiAuth', function ($http, $document) {
        var clientId = '<YOUR CLIENT ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        //The client ID, NECESSARY
        var apiKey = 'WHAT WAS THIS USED FOR? GOOD QUESTION IDK';
        //Api Key 
        var scopes = ['profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
        //The scopes, of which you will need
        var authService = this;
        //this is here just in case we need it later

        var gapi_el = $document.find('#gapi-load');
        //finding the gapi element added in because this needs to load.

        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        //is the current user logged in? this is mostly for ease of use.

        this.gapiProcessed = false;
        //This is used as a quick way to figure out whether or not the gapi is set and ready because Google is a bag of dicks.

        /*
            function ready:
                @params success_cb : function
                    Called when gapi is set and ready.
        */
        this.loadGapiWait = function () {
            console.log(this);
            if (gapi_el.attr('gapi_processed') != "true") {
                console.log('Nope!', gapi_el.attr('gapi_processed'));
                window.setTimeout(this.loadGapiWait.bind(this), 500);
                return;
            }
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                'client_id': clientId,
                'scope': scopes.join(' '),
                'immediate': true
            }, this.handleAuthResult);
        }

        $document.ready(this.loadGapiWait.bind(this));
        // we are using the $document object because... I am lazy. 

        this.initAuth = function (isImmediate) {
            isImmediate = isImmediate || false;
            //If the call is immediate or not (we try for an immediate call first for users who have already authorized us.)

            gapi.auth.authorize({
                'client_id': clientId,
                'scope': scopes.join(' '),
                'immediate': isImmediate
            }, this.handleAuthResult.bind(this));

        }.bind(this); //end gapi.auth.authorize()

        ; //end initAuth;

        this.handleAuthResult = function (authResult) {
            console.log("this is ", this);
            var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
                authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
                this.loadCalendarApi();
            } else {
                // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
                // clicking authorize button.
                authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
            }
        }.bind(this);

        /**
         * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
         *
         * @param {Event} event Button click event.
         */
        this.handleAuthClick = function (event) {
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                    client_id: clientId,
                    scope: scopes,
                    immediate: false
                },
                this.handleAuthResult);
            return false;
        }.bind(this);

        /**
         * Load Google Calendar client library. List upcoming events
         * once client library is loaded.
         */

        this.loadCalendarApi = function () {
            gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', this.listUpcomingEvents);
        }.bind(this);

        /**
         * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
         * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
         * appropriate message is printed.
         */
        this.listUpcomingEvents = function () {
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list(
                /*{
                            'calendarId': 'primary',
                            'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
                            'showDeleted': false,
                            'singleEvents': true,
                            'maxResults': 10,
                            'orderBy': 'startTime'
                        }*/
            );

            request.execute(function (resp) {
                var events = resp.items;
                console.log("Response object !!!:", resp);
                appendPre('Upcoming events:');
                if (events.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                        var event = events[i];

                        appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + (event.primary || false) + ')')
                    }
                } else {
                    appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
                }

            });
        }.bind(this);


    });

function appendPre(thing){
    var pre = angular.element(document).find('#pre-div');
    pre.append(thing);

}
```